# Issue with getting "gooey" CSS SVG filter for rounded text background to work in Firefox

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-filters

I was attempting to recreate the following rounded background effect found in [this Dribble design](https://dribbble.com/shots/20324434-365MAG-Article):

[image: desired effect]

Through some research, I found out that it was called [the gooey effect](https://css-tricks.com/gooey-effect/). I tried to implement these [Text Background With Gooey Filter](Text Background With Gooey Filter) and [Gooey text background with SVG filters](https://codepen.io/ines/pen/NXbmRO?editors=1100), but they don't work on Firefox. I'm looking for that **rounded inner corner effect** that displays on Chrome.

Here is my attempt:

```html
<p>I just want to smile and live life and enjoy every moment while I still have it.</p>


<svg style="display: none">
  <defs>
    <filter id="gooey-filter">
      <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" result="blur" stdDeviation="7.5"/>
      <feColorMatrix in="blur" result="colormatrix"
        type="matrix"
        values="1 0 0 0 0
                0 1 0 0 0
                0 0 1 0 0
                0 0 0 58 -9" />
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="colormatrix"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap');

body {
  font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 3em;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 50px;
  max-width: 25ch;
}

p {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.5em;
  line-height: 1.3;
  background: #D1FB96;
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;
  filter: url('#gooey-filter');
}

span:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

On Chrome-based browsers, it looks like this: (notice the **rounded inner corner**)
[image: on Chrome]

On Firefox, it looks like this: (sharp inner edges)

[image: On Firefox]

I'm aware that the [gooey effect has been revisited](https://codepen.io/ccprog/pen/jaRGze), but I'm not sure how to implement the changes to a text-based example to get that **rounded inner corner**.

[Here's my codepen](https://codepen.io/candidee/pen/QWzmBXy)

Comment: The filter is not being applied at all in Firefox because you have the SVG set to display:none - so the filter is being removed from the DOM entirely (which is the correct behavior - Chrome is accepting bad syntax, trying to make your life easier).

Comment: @MichaelMullany: Unfortunately, removing the display:none still doesn't add the rounded inner corner effect to the background of the text.

Comment: You're applying the filter at the wrong level - the filter is being applied to the p before the line is wrapped by your max-width, so it's not being gooey'd. If you add a wrapper div around the p and apply the filter to that element it works.

Comment: @MichaelMullany : Removing `display: none;` and adding a `<div>` solved it. [Updated pen](https://codepen.io/candidee/pen/zYyaZjP?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an inner span with `position: relative` style.

```html
<p>
  <span style="position:relative">
    I just want to smile and live life and enjoy every moment while I still have it.
  </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't add inner curvature to the background on Firefox...